# Encoding hex value with UTF8 of Ascii representation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, utf-8, asciiencoding

I have a nsdata with bytes :0017c572 528e
now i need to encode this byte using either UTF 8 of Ascii 
For this i have used following code in Objective C

```
 NSString *Str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

then later on at some point i need to get back the same bytes from Str for this i have used

```
  NSData *aData = [Str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSLog(@"aData:%@", aData);
```

Now the problem is content of aData is null not  0017c572 528e . how can i do the this operation.

this concept works perfectly  if data byte is : 323332

```
str = 232
aData = 323332
```

Comment: You need to work around zero bytes separately, zero is the string terminator so you have to encode it somehow, or store it in something which can handle zeros in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Just print the `Str` value before the line

```
  NSLog(@"Str = %@",Str);
  NSData *aData = [Str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

It seems the `Str` variable does not have any value. Then only, it will return `null`. Please check.